# Get attribute using ActionChains in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, pytest

We are writing Automation scripts using Selenium Pytest and is trying to get the value in a textbox. The textbox is having a label inside a  element (which is used as the locator). However there is another  inside and the input is inside the second div (which houses the actual values. There are no built in unique locators available and hence I have used the below locator. Please note that the actual page is having 10 similar textboxes with same HTML as mentioned here, but differing in the textbox names only.

```
"//label[contains(., 'Textbox')]"
```

Now I had to click and type on the textbox for which normal selenium click method was returning *ElementClickInterceptedException*, due to which I had to use ActionChains.
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath(element)).click().send_keys("sample").perform()

Now the issue is that I have to get the value of the data in the textbox. I have tried the below

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(element).get_attribute('value')
```

But it did not work as expected and returned the same *ElementNotInteractableException*. Please suggest if I can get attribute of the value in the input using any other method. I have already tried the below without much luck, as it returned Nonetype.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(element).text
```

I have also tried using all other locator combinations, but only the one stated above was found to be working. Please suggest whether there is any way to get the attribute values using ActionChains itself.

Edit #

1. Adding HTML below as suggested in the comments.

'''

```
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-marginNormal MuiFormControl-fullWidth"><label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined MuiFormLabel-filled" data-shrink="true" for="mui-76404" id="mui-76404-label">Textbox</label><div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-adornedEnd MuiOutlinedInput-adornedEnd"><input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiOutlinedInput-inputAdornedEnd" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="value" id="mui-76404"><div class="MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment"><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicator" tabindex="-1" type="button" aria-label="Clear" title="Clear"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeSmall" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator" tabindex="-1" type="button" aria-label="Open" title="Open"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button></div><fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="jss229 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline"><legend class="jss231 jss232"><span>Textbox</span></legend></fieldset></div></div>
```

I have already tried with the below locators without much success. They are working for click action, but is not working when am trying to get attribute.

```
"//label[contains(., 'Textbox')]/div/input"
"//div[contains(., 'Textbox')]/div/input"
```

2. Adding screenshot of empty value getting returned while trying Option # 1 suggested below by @PDHide.
   [image]

Comment: Please add the HTML of the element you are trying to use `.get_attribute('value')` on.

Comment: or just share the URL of the page, makes it easier for the possible helpers

Comment: @Jortega
Added HTML above as suggested

Comment: can you make a new line per html row or smth? its pretty hard to read that xD

Comment: are you selecting the text box or the label?

Comment: @DMart, I am trying to access the textbox using the label as there are no unique locators for the textbox.

Comment: I think the problem is you're trying ot getAttribute of the label, not the text box

Comment: @DMart, the label is used as the locator as there are no single unique locators for the textbox.

Comment: checkout using next sibling as part of your locator.

Comment: @DMart, can you suggest how that has to be done?
It would great if you can add the suggestion in the answer for more clarity

Comment: Look at https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-siblings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send key to label tag which is not interactable. You have to interact with the input tag. There are two ways to do it :

**1. use switch to active element:**

```
locator= "//label[contains(., 'Textbox')]"

textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
textbox.click()

inputElement = driver.switch_to.active_element
inputElement.send_keys("HIHIHIHIHI")

print(inputElement.get_attribute('value'))

print(textbox.text)
```

**2. Directly use the input element:**

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(., 'Textbox')]/..//input")

inputElement.send_keys("HIHIHIHIHI")

print(inputElement.get_attribute('value'))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: please see the following section in the HTML..

<label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined MuiFormLabel-filled" data-shrink="true" for="mui-76404" id="mui-76404-label">Textbox</label>

Comment: Then what is the html added in the question?

Comment: Its included in the HTML in the question as well @PDHide. Kindly go through the HTML fully.

Comment: jss232"><span>Textbox</span></legend></fieldset></div></div>

Comment: That's what there in the html

Comment: Please check the start of the HTML @PDHide.

Comment: I have copied the HTML snippet in the comments directly from the HTML in the question

Comment: @ArunSasi have added the answer , you where trying to send text to label tag. instead you have to send to input tag. You can find this tag directly or just use switch to active element after clicking the label

Comment: you can print the content using get attribute value

Comment: fwiw it's a little confusing to name the label variable textbox, when it's actually the label.

Comment: @PDHide, Tried both the options above and following are the results:

Comment: 1. Didn't return an error, but the returned an empty string.

Comment: Add your screenshot of the output ,

Comment: Did the value got entered ?

Comment: 2. Had tried with this earlier as well. It returns NoSuchElementException for both click and getattribute

Comment: @ArunSasi this was with the html you provided its working when i tried , when you tried first option what is getting printed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225349/discussion-between-arun-sasi-and-pdhide).